# How do you change the frequency of the usage reports?

Tags: site-usage

Currently it looks like the usage reports I get from site settings > Popularity and Search Reports are updated nightly. This results in an excel graph with the current day always empty.

The **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing** job was disabled but I was still getting the daily report. I enabled it and ran the job but the report did not update.

What timer job should I update to get them on a more frequent basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

building the reports there are multiple timer jobs running:

> •Analytics Timer Job for Search Service Application Search Service
> Application
>
> •Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import
>
> •Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing
>
> •Usage Analytics Timer Job for Search Application Search Service
> Application

below is taking you to the location, you need to follow it through.... but not all as you have it running already and want to change the setting which number 8 outlines:

**Configure usage and health data collection by using Central Administration**

> To configure usage and health data collection by using Central
> Administration:
>
> **1.** Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:
>
> The user account that performs this procedure has to be a member of
> the Farm Administrators group.
>
> **2.** In Central Administration, on the home page, click Monitoring.
>
> **3.** On the Monitoring page, in the Reporting section, click Configure usage and health data collection.
>
> **4.** On the Configure usage and health data collection page, in the Usage Data Collection section, select the Enable usage data collection check
> box.
>
> **5.** In the Event Selection section, select the check boxes of the events that you want to log.
>
> Logging uses system resources and can affect performance and disk
> usage. Only log those events for which you want regular reports.
>
> For impromptu reports or investigations, enable logging for events,
> and then disable logging for the events after the report or
> investigation is complete. For more information, see Configure usage
> data collection for events by using Windows PowerShell.
>
> **6.** In the Usage Data Collection Settings section, type the path of the folder to which you want usage and health information to be written in
> the Log file location box. The path that you specify must exist on
> each server in the farm.
>
> These settings are applied to all events.
>
> **7.** In the Health Data Collection section, select the Enable health data collection check box. To change the collection schedules, click Health
> Logging Schedule. You can see a list of timer jobs that collect health
> data. Click any of the timer jobs to change its schedule, or disable
> that timer job. If you disable a timer job, it stops collecting
> corresponding health data. For more information, see Timer job
> reference (SharePoint 2013).
>
> **8.** To change log collection schedules, click Log Collection Schedule, and then click any of the timer jobs to change its schedule, or
> disable that timer job. If you disable a timer job, it stops
> collecting corresponding log data.
>
> **9.** In the Logging Database Server section, to change the authentication method, select either the Windows authentication or SQL authentication
> option.
>
> To change the Database Server and Database Name values, you must use
> Windows PowerShell. For more information, see Log usage data in a
> different logging database by using Windows PowerShell.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663480.aspx